# Angular 2 with ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am new to Angular 2. I don't know to use Angular 2 with ASP.NET MVC.

My question is: I am developing basic login and register application in ASP.NET MVC with Angular 2

My questions are:

1. What is the role of an ASP.NET MVC view in Angular 2?
2. Should I create views in View folder rather than app folder in which angular typscript files lies.
3. What is the best way to create Views in application with ASP.NET MVC and Angular
4. How to connect front-end with back-end (database specially Microsoft SQL Server)? How to call controller in Angular 2 application ? I found about, How to manage routing of ASP.NET MVC and Angular 2. But I don't know how to get the data from controller to Angular typescript file?

Right now, I have created HTMl files in app folder instead of Views folder.

My folder structure is

```
|app
 +-login
 +---login.component.html
 +---login.component.ts
 +-register
 +---register.component.html
 +---register.component.ts
 +-app.component.ts
 +-app.module.ts
 +-main.ts
 +-routing.module.ts
|Controllers
 +-HomeController.cs
|Models
|Views
 +-Home
 +--Index.cshtml
```

My Index.cshtml file contains

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

My `HomeController.cs` contains:

```
namespace BasicAngular.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you just have to download the angular js file and include it into your project. Then just add the reference to the cshtml page that you want to use angular in

Comment: But I don't know how to call MVC Controller and view from angular 2

Comment: read on google how to make ajax calls from angular.